# Como instanciar uma model dentro da outra na view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-blade

> Erro: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

MIGRATION DIVIDA

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateDividasTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('dividas', function (Blueprint $table) {


            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('numdoc')->nullable();

            $table->integer('cliente_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('cliente_id')->references('id')->on('clientes');

            $table->integer('devedor_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('devedor_id')->references('id')->on('devedors');

            $table->date('data_emissao');
            $table->date('data_debito');

            $table->integer('meses_atraso')->default(0);
            $table->integer('multa')->default(0);
            $table->double('valor_multa')->default(0);

            $table->double('taxa')->default(0);
            $table->double('valor');
            $table->double('valor_recebido')->default(0);
            $table->double('valor_aberto')->default(0);
            $table->double('valor_total_corrigido')->default(0);

            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('status')->default('pendente');
            $table->timestamps();

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('dividas');
    }
}
```

MIGRATION TITULO

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTitulosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('titulos', function (Blueprint $table) {

            // cadastro padrão
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('referencia');

            $table->integer('tipo_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('tipo_id')->references('id')->on('titulo_tipos');

            $table->integer('divida_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('divida_id')->references('id')->on('dividas');


            $table->integer('user_id');

            $table->date('vencimento_titulo')->nullable();
            $table->double('valor')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            // fim cadastro padrão




        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('titulos');
        Schema::dropIfExists('devedors');
        //Schema::dropIfExists('clientes');

    }
}
```

MODEL DIVIDA

```
 public function titulo()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Titulo');
    }
```

MODEL TITULO

```
public function divida()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Divida', 'divida_id');
    }
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Gostaria de acessar campos da tabela titulo em divida

Comment: Ex.: $divida->titulo->valor

Comment: Coloque os Model na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te aconselharia a não utilizar chaves estrangeiras no banco, é uma responsabilidade do front manter a integridade, além disso caso planeje escalar horizontalmente seu banco isso inviabilizaria e muito essa tarefa. utilie direto no seu model e não no banco.

Faça sua migration apenas assim:

```
$table->integer('tipo_id');
```

E no seu model de titulos faça:

```
 public function tipos()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Tipo', 'id', 'tipo_id);
    }
```

Creio que seu titulo possua apenas um tipo, e um tipo poderá ter vários títulos ai no model de tipo faça:

```
 public function titulos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Titulos', 'tipo_id', 'id');
    }
```

Alguns bons artigos sobre:

https://medium.com/@hernandev/sempre-use-chaves-estrangeiras-no-mysql-e24b4e2187f5

https://medium.com/@lemesdaniel/o-porqu%C3%AA-de-eu-n%C3%A3o-usar-chave-estrangeira-no-mysql-2e0179af4b2c

Answer (score 0):

O  relacionamento hasMany, representa uma relacionamento de **um para muitos**.

Ver
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

No seu caso uma dívida muitos títulos.

**Nota:**
O método no modelo Divida devia chamar-se  titulos e não titulo porque representa uma colecção de títulos e não  um título.

Neste caso está  tentar obter "valor" a partir da colecção, o que não vai funcionar.

Os relacionamentos são devolvidos sob a forma  de uma Collection

Ver
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections

Exemplo para obter o primeiro item da colecção pode fazer.

```
$divida->titulos->first()->valor
```

Exemplo para  verificar se existem títulos associados à dívida.

```
$divida->titulos->isEmpty()
```

Última nota, consulte a documentação sobre Eager Loading para evitar problemas com com consultas à base de dados do  tipo  N+1

Ver

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading